# how to run a function from parent element inside the child element?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I got 2 components. Navbar (parent) & Setting Menu(Child)

```
const Navbar: React.FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [randomState, setrandomState] = useState(false);


  const randomStateFunction = () =>{
    setrandomState(!randomState)
  }

return (
     <SettingsMenu randomState={randomState} randomStateSetter={randomStateFunction} />
)


 };
```

Here is the child element

```
    type NavbarProps = {
      randomStateSetter?: () => void;
      randomState?: boolean;
    };
    
    type SettingsMenuProps = RouteComponentProps & NavbarProps;



export class SettingsMenu extends Component<
   SettingsMenuProps,
   SettingsMenuState
   > {
      constructor(props: SettingsMenuProps) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          settingsAnchorElement: null,
          currentDialog: null,
          showLoginButton: false,
        };
      }

private signInWithGoogle = async (e: React.MouseEvent): Promise<void> => {
    // For now, google is our only provider.
    const creds = await firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPopup(AuthenticationProviders.google);
    await firebase.auth().updateCurrentUser(creds.user);
    await this.props.randomStateSetter
  };


    return(
    <GoogleButton onClick={(e: React.MouseEvent) => {
       this.signInWithGoogle(e); }}/>
    )
```

As you can see in the return statement. I am calling the this.props.randomStateSetter inside a function.
The `this.props.randomStatesetter` function run perfectly on write directly on the onclick handler. But the when called inside a function

this error log is shown `Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  @typescript-eslint/no-unused-expressions`

can anyone explain

Comment: `randomStateSetter?: () => void;` and `await this.props.randomStateSetter` you are awaiting on a function? **You never call the function.**

Comment: You need to call the function too... `this.props.randomStateSetter()`

Comment: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.
I got this comment when i write with () @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen

Comment: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined' I got this comment when i write with () @DennisVash

Comment: I don't understand why people give - to questions :(
Now i can't get an answer. I understand when giving minus when asking duplicate question or not understandable question. sigh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are never calling `this.props.randomStatesetter`, to call it you would do `this.props.randomStatesetter()` however because it may be undefined you will need to do some optional chaining:

```
this.props.randomStatesetter?.()
```

this will call it if it's not undefined and leave it alone if it is undefined.  I'm not totally sure why you are awaiting on it also, may want to specify in the props it is expected to be async:

```
type NavbarProps = {
  randomStateSetter?: () => Promise<void>;
  randomState?: boolean;
};
```

Or to not always be async but give some indication that being async is fine (this is functionally equivalent to what you already have but gives clearer intent:

```
type NavbarProps = {
  randomStateSetter?: () => void | Promise<void>;
  randomState?: boolean;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I am stuck here for 3 hours now.
I don't even know about optional chaining. will try to understand it.
I am afraid of not getting an answer because people usually skip minus question.